# Why migrate a question to a stack on which it is even more off-topic than it already was?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

I asked [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/128735/interstellar-reefs-plausibility-and-detection) some hours ago, a question which turns out to be more complex and have more implications built into than is useful, so it was closed, that's fine by me. But then it was migrated, to the Space Exploration stack, 30 seconds due diligence shows that hypothetical questions are on shaky ground on Space Exploration and that this question in particular has no place whatsoever on the site as originally written (as written it's a better fit on the Astronomy stack and off-topic even there).

A suggestion had been made, and acknowledged by me, that there *might* be a case for posting a question on the same topic to Space Exploration and I indicated that I would investigate that possibility once the post had been up for 24 hours so the whole community had a chance to see it and maybe answer it as by then a couple of suggests had been made already. I've been led to believe that it is the polite way to handle things once a post is up and has answers; to let it be for at least a full day before doing something as drastic as closing it myself. I intended to check the parameters of Space Exploration and see what parts, if any, of the question were site compatible and proceed accordingly. I signed back in to find that the question had been migrated and a glance at the "what can I ask" section of its new home tells me it shouldn't be there, *at all*. Furthermore I'm stuck with it because it's still carrying the answers it got on this stack to spite them both being deleted by their authors on this stack.

I don't object to the question being closed, it was bigger and less useful than I thought it was, I don't object in general to the idea of questions being migrated. In this case however the question has been put even further at odds with the policies of the stack it is on than it already was because it was migrated into a space that deals almost exclusively in established science rather than hypothetical questions.

So would it not be A. prudent to check the parameters for questions on the sites we're migrating material to, especially in light of the fact that we work with a lot of hypothetical material that is completely off-topic elsewhere in the network? And/or B. when a question needs to be closed but the topic *may* be answerable elsewhere on the network tell the OP that and let them decide how much, if any, of that question they want to put on another site?

Comment: Oops thank you @α CVn I looked at that tag and then got distracted by the lack of an etiquette tag.

Comment: I wasn't involved with the migration, but I thought your couldn't force the migration of a question to any other stack.  They must agree to receive it.  Am I wrong?  If not, a good corrolary question to this one is why [space.se] bothered to accept migration of a question they knew wasn't an appropriate fit for their site.

Comment: @JBH Yeah it took Space Exploration a couple of days but they did eventually reject the migration.

Comment: @JBH A diamond moderator can migrate a question to any site in the network. The migration target site is never involved in the migration per se, but can reject the migration, by closing as something other than a duplicate. While there seems to have been some disagreement over on [space.se] as to the exact close reason to use, that seems to be what happened in this case.

Comment: Did you read called2voyage's comment? It belongs on [astronomy.se]

Comment: I sincerely apologize for the role I played in this. I should have paid more attention when I was trying to suggest the more appropriate SE. Please forgive my error.

Comment: @JanDoggen Actually it doesn't, the original question _as written_ doesn't belong anywhere, part of it is appropriate to Space Exploration and part of it sort of fits on Astronomy but the question as a whole doesn't fit either one.